# Access multiple shared resource with multiple threads in java

Tags: java

I am trying to insert values in three shared arrays through two thread.  Where the conditions are if an array is a accessed by only one thread but thread can use another array.
For example c1, c2, c3 are three arrays and t1 and t2 are two thread then if t1 is using c1 then t2 can not use c1 but it can use c2 or c3. The same condition applied to t2.
please help if someone knew how to code this scenario.

Comment: Just use three different accessor methods for three arrays, with all the methods using lock on different object, perhaps on the array itself.

Comment: all the time only first array is being used by all threads, other arrays are empty. I want if one thread is using an array then at same time other thread should use other arrays do not wait for first to complete.

Comment: And this is exactly what my solution is for

Comment: then please if you have some code then share so that I can understand because I am not getting your point.

Comment: Just write three different methods with synchronisation block taking lock on the array for which the method is for.

Comment: synchronized(l1){
           c1.add(i);
       }
       synchronized(l2){
           c2.add(i);
       }
       synchronized(l3){
           c3.add(i);
       }// like this ...

Answer (score 2):

As has been commented you can use synchronized blocks or alternatively you could use a Lock:

```
        Lock lockA, lockB, lockC;

        ...

        if (lockA.tryLock()) {
            try {
                // write to c1
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO
            } finally {
                lockA.unlock();
            }
        } else if (lockB.tryLock()) {
            try {
                // write to c2
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO
            } finally {
                lockB.unlock();
            }
        } else if (lockC.tryLock()) {
            try {
                // write to c3
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO
            } finally {
                lockC.unlock();
            }
        } else {
           // Cant get to anything as all three are locked!!!
        }

        ...
```

The `tryLock()` method returns true if the lock is available and gives the lock to the thread calling the method otherwise it returns false.

Once a thread has the lock it can then perform the operation it needs on the array and no other thread can do anything to that array during this time.

The `unlock()` method in the `finally` block is then executed once the operation has completed which then frees up the lock and allows other threads to perform that operation.

Comment: In this way, all the threads are using all the arrays. For Example t1 and t2 threads want to insert 10 elements in c1, c2, an c3. then t1 and t2 are inserting their data to all three arrays. same element is inserting in all arrays.......I want if t1 any one of them not all of them.

Comment: the above example does as you described initially. please explain a little clearer as to what you mean and i will try and answer the best i can..

Comment: See c1, c2 and c3 are shared arrays. t1 and t2 two independent thread both have same values to store in c1 or c2 or c3. If t1 should store a value in 'any one of the array.' if t1 is using c1 at that time t2 can use c2 or c3 so that t1 and t2 both are trying to insert then t1 can insert in c1 and t2 can insert in c2 or c3 at the same time.

Comment: my above example does as you described...put a Thread.sleep(5000) in each of the locks and you will see that when your second thread comes to write to c1 it is locked by the first thread so tries the lock for c2 and finds its free so writes to c2. c3 is pretty pointless if you only have two threads as you'll only ever be writing to either c1 or c2 unless you lock two of the arrays with the same thread forcing the second thread to use c3...

Comment: but in the above solution... both threads are inserting their data in all three arrays. one thread only use a array to insert an element not the same value insert in all three arrays.

Comment: please add your code and we will go from there...the use of `else if` means it won't go through all of the operations, it will just try the first one, if that's not free it will try the second and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This Problem Is **Synchronization** Problem So That Concurrency or Mutual Exclusion Could be Occurs If You Need To Solve This You Should Choose one Of This Algorithms and Techniques According to Your Problem .
**Here Is The Techniques And Algorithms With It Implementation In Java :**

- **Dekker's Algorithm** [Dekker Implementation](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF431/X13-2014-2015/TD/INF431-td_3a-1.php)
- **Semaphore** [Implementation Of Semaphore](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html)
- **Monitors** 
  You can Also Search to Find Suitable Tutorial and Implementation For Your Problem